# Cancelling an in-progress WSAPI/LBAPI request

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I have been developing an app which processes many WSAPI and LBAPI requests which take an extended period of time to complete. In the event that certain parameters are changed, these requests become irrelevant and canceling them would be the best thing to do, in an effort to clear up the network queue for the new set of requests that need to take place.

I have searched the docs of both APIs and haven't been able to find any way included in the SDK to cancel these requests. I'm wondering if there might be a way to do this manually, or if there is a function I might be missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't found it because it doesn't exist in Ext.  :-)  We have run into similar things in the past but haven't had a critical need to build this into the framework yet.

The best info I've found on this problem is this post which describes how to augment stores to support canceling outstanding loads:

http://www.mattgoldspink.co.uk/2013/02/03/ext-js-cancel-a-load-on-an-ext-data-store/